# Increase speed sending static images with nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, express

I have a typical **client/server** application where i can send images to the server and i need that image on the client with diferent sizes.

So at the moment i am using Picasso with android to load the image, and with nodeJS i am serving the images as static files, since they are saved in the folder where the static files are.

My question is: is there a way to increase the speed sending this static files(just the images), or can i decrease the size of them using the code that i currently have for the static file?

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

at the moment i receive the image from the client as **base64** and on the server i convert it to a bitmap like this:

var bitmap = new Buffer(req.body.base64, 'base64');

and store that bitmap on the public folder that i use as a static folder, i dont store the image directly on the database since that is bad practice, i just save the path and everytime i want to retrive the image i know inside the static folder where it is.

So everytime on my client that i want to retrive a foto i just need to know what is the static path, nothing more.

For a better understanding i leave here the code for 1 of my controllers where i save the photo.

**controller**

```
sendPicture: function (req, res, next) {
        var plant = null
        if (req.params.id != 0) {
            plant = req.params.id;
        }
        var bitmap = new Buffer(req.body.base64, 'base64');
        var lat = req.body.lat;
        var lon = req.body.lon;
        var alt = req.body.alt;
        var date = req.body.date;
        var flowerName;
        var pathId = shortid.generate();
        var userId = req.userId;

        if (plant != null) {
            Plant.findOne({
                where: { id: req.params.id }
            }).then(function (plant) {
                if (!plant) {
                    return 'not found';
                }
                flowerName = plant.specie;
            }).then(function () {

                var pathToSave = __dirname + "/../public/images/" + flowerName + "/" + pathId + req.params.id + "-" + userId + ".jpg";
                var path = "images/" + flowerName + "/" + pathId + req.params.id + "-" + userId + ".jpg"


                fsPath.writeFile(pathToSave, bitmap, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err.stack);
                        return err;
                    }
                    Foto.create({
                        image: path,
                        userId: userId,
                        plantId: req.params.id,
                        lat: req.body.lat,
                        lon: req.body.lon,
                        alt: req.body.alt,
                        date: date,
                    }).then(function () {
                        return res.status(200).json({ message: "foto created" });
                    }).catch(function (err) {
                        console.log(err.stack);
                    })

                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Don’t use Express to serve static files; put a reverse proxy like [Nginx](https://nginx.org/) in front of it instead. Then you’ll probably want to generate more optimized images in the first place, but it’s hard to give advice on that without knowing how you’re doing it.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i updated my question with a little more details, is Nginx to complex to use with the current solution?